# root update: internal error: unsupported substitution string -kbx

Tags: cvs, netbeans-8

I checked out Java project to NetBeans from a cvs repository, made some changes, tried to run diff and got the following error:

`root update: internal error: unsupported substitution string -kbx`

Previously checkouts, commits and diff worked well. What can be causing this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you altered the structure of a project and moved unrelated cvs folder to sources. Plugin gets confused about actual version and causes this error.

If you placed unrelated cvs folders - delete them and try to checkout the project one more time.